# cant use begin() for array in c++

Tags: c++

I am using g++ 7.1.0, yet using begin() with array as an argument throws an error. My code is

```
#include <iostream>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    int a[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin>>a[i];
    }
    sort(begin(a), end(a));
    return 0;
}
```

It says

```
no matching function for call to 'begin(int [n])'
```

Comment: Obligatory _are you compiling with C++11_ comment

Comment: How do I find that?

Comment: What is your command to compile? If it doesn't include `-std=c++11` then you aren't using C++11

Comment: Im compiling this on HackerEarth. There is no way for me to do something like g++ test.cpp -std=c++11

Comment: Then do `sort(a, a + n);` . Still, VLA's aren't standard. Don't rely on them too much.

Comment: @SherinBinu HarkerRank doesn't have g++ 7.1. See [here](https://www.hackerrank.com/environment). Also all compilers flags have c++11 enabled AFAIK

Comment: @StoryTeller  Im also using find() function later. Im not sure I can perform find() operation without end()

Comment: @P0W Well, Why its not working for me then?

Comment: You can use any standard algorithm with an array. You just can't rely on `begin` and `end` to evaluate into `a` and `a + n` for you. That's what they do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int a[n];` is invalid statement in C++. C++ doesn't allow variable length array. It is allowed only in C since C99 standard. If you need dynamic array, you should be using [*std::vector*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) 99% of the time in C++.

You can do this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::cout<<"Enter size of array\n";
    int size;
    std::cin>>size;

    std::vector<int> v(size);
    std::cout<<"Enter "<<size<< " elements\n";
    for(size_t i=0;i<v.size();++i)
        std::cin>>v[i];

    std::sort(v.begin(),v.end());

    std::cout<<"Sorted elements are: \n";

    for(const auto& i : v)
        std::cout<<i<<' ';
}
```

See live demo [here](http://cpp.sh/8epak).

Answer (score 2):

`#include <iterator>`

`<algorithm>` is the [wrong header](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) for `begin()`, `end()`, and, well, all the iteration functions.

Also, for the iteration functions to work, the array must be sized with a compile-time constant, so, `int a[10];` works, but `int a[n];` does not.

Comment: It's late.  Fixed.

Comment: It also must be a compile-time constant sized array.

Comment: This answer is correct. If this isn't working, you're likely not compiling with C++11

Comment: @Tas Variable length arrays are not part of any C++ standard. Some compilers provide them as an extension. I'm not really surprised that `std::begin()` and `std::end()`  don't work with VLAs.

Comment: I tried with http://cpp.sh, and although it accepts VLAs, the iteration functions do not work with them.

Comment: Good to know! I'll cleanup my comments

Answer (score 1):

you can do this:-

```
#include <algorithm>
int main(){
   int arr[2000];
   int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
   std::sort(arr, arr+n);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using array instead of vector then use

```
sort(a,a+n);
```